# What causes this and how to fix: Error code: SSL_ERROR_NO_CYPHER_OVERLAP

Tags: wordpress, ssl, google-cloud-platform, bitnami, gcp-load-balancer

I'm migrating a bitnami wordpress site from AWS lightsail to GCP.

The AWS's setup includes a purchased wildcard SSL. When I set up the loadbalancer in GCP, I opt for Google's SSL instead.

I got this error `Error code: SSL_ERROR_NO_CYPHER_OVERLAP` when I access from the loadbalancer's IP. The VM is working fine and I am able to access it with it's own external IP.

The domain is still pointing to AWS's server. I wonder if the error is because I have not pointed the domain to the load balancer's IP?

I'm hoping to gain some clarity first before I update the domain's IP. I want to avoid situation where it does not work after I make the switch.

Thanks

Comment: You will need to provide a lot more details. Basically, the error means that the client and the server could not agree on an encryption cipher. This can happen when one side is using old software (Firefox?). Suggestion: configure everything correctly first. Then test connections.

Comment: @JohnHanley Thank you. Accessing via VM's ext.IP works fine. Health check status is ok. Can these two points be considered as correctly configured? May I know what other information to provide or what other areas i need to look into to be certain of it? The error is produced by Firefox. On Chrome's ```ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH```.

Comment: Details are required. What version of Firefox for example? I commented that the error is typically caused by old out of date software. If Firefox is old, update it.

Comment: Hi @JohnHanley Firefox 89.0

Comment: Try checking your cert with this command - https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl-certificates/troubleshooting?&_ga=2.217938390.-151873027.1594931962#domain-status
and post anonymized results.